# Running SICP Pattern Matching Rule Based Substitution Code

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, sicp

I have found the code from this lesson online (http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/6.001-fall91/ps4/matcher-from-lecture.scm), and I am having a heck of a time trying to debug it.  The code looks pretty comparable to what Sussman has written:

```
;;; Scheme code from the Pattern Matcher lecture

;; Pattern Matching and Simplification

(define (match pattern expression dictionary)
  (cond ((eq? dictionary 'failed) 'failed)
        ((atom? pattern)
         (if (atom? expression)
             (if (eq? pattern expression)
                 dictionary
                 'failed)
             'failed))
        ((arbitrary-constant? pattern)
         (if (constant? expression)
             (extend-dictionary pattern expression dictionary)
             'failed))
        ((arbitrary-variable? pattern)
         (if (variable? expression)
             (extend-dictionary pattern expression dictionary)
             'failed))
        ((arbitrary-expression? pattern)
         (extend-dictionary pattern expression dictionary))
        ((atom? expression) 'failed)
        (else
         (match (cdr pattern)
                (cdr expression)
                (match (car pattern)
                       (car expression)
                       dictionary)))))

(define (instantiate skeleton dictionary)
  (cond ((atom? skeleton) skeleton)
        ((skeleton-evaluation? skeleton)
         (evaluate (evaluation-expression skeleton)
                   dictionary))
        (else (cons (instantiate (car skeleton) dictionary)
                    (instantiate (cdr skeleton) dictionary)))))

(define (simplifier the-rules)
  (define (simplify-exp exp)
    (try-rules (if (compound? exp)
                   (simplify-parts exp)
                   exp)))
  (define (simplify-parts exp)
    (if (null? exp)
        '()
        (cons (simplify-exp   (car exp))
              (simplify-parts (cdr exp)))))
  (define (try-rules exp)
    (define (scan rules)
      (if (null? rules)
          exp
          (let ((dictionary (match (pattern (car rules))
                                   exp
                                   (make-empty-dictionary))))
            (if (eq? dictionary 'failed)
                (scan (cdr rules))
                (simplify-exp (instantiate (skeleton (car rules))
                                           dictionary))))))
    (scan the-rules))
  simplify-exp)

;; Dictionaries 

(define (make-empty-dictionary) '())

(define (extend-dictionary pat dat dictionary)
  (let ((vname (variable-name pat)))
    (let ((v (assq vname dictionary)))
      (cond ((null? v)
             (cons (list vname dat) dictionary))
            ((eq? (cadr v) dat) dictionary)
            (else 'failed)))))

(define (lookup var dictionary)
  (let ((v (assq var dictionary)))
    (if (null? v)
        var
        (cadr v))))

;; Expressions

(define (compound? exp) (pair?   exp))
(define (constant? exp) (number? exp))
(define (variable? exp) (atom?   exp))

;; Rules

(define (pattern  rule) (car  rule))
(define (skeleton rule) (cadr rule))

;; Patterns

(define (arbitrary-constant?    pattern)
  (if (pair? pattern) (eq? (car pattern) '?c) false))

(define (arbitrary-expression?  pattern)
  (if (pair? pattern) (eq? (car pattern) '? ) false))

(define (arbitrary-variable?    pattern)
  (if (pair? pattern) (eq? (car pattern) '?v) false))

(define (variable-name pattern) (cadr pattern))

;; Skeletons & Evaluations

(define (skeleton-evaluation?    skeleton)
  (if (pair? skeleton) (eq? (car skeleton) ':) false))

(define (evaluation-expression evaluation) (cadr evaluation))


;; Evaluate (dangerous magic)

(define (evaluate form dictionary)
  (if (atom? form)
      (lookup form dictionary)
      (apply (eval (lookup (car form) dictionary)
                   user-initial-environment)
             (mapcar (lambda (v) (lookup v dictionary))
                     (cdr form)))))

;;
;; A couple sample rule databases...
;;

;; Algebraic simplification

(define algebra-rules
  '(
    ( ((? op) (?c c1) (?c c2))                (: (op c1 c2))                )
    ( ((? op) (?  e ) (?c c ))                ((: op) (: c) (: e))          )
    ( (+ 0 (? e))                             (: e)                         )
    ( (* 1 (? e))                             (: e)                         )
    ( (* 0 (? e))                             0                             )
    ( (* (?c c1) (* (?c c2) (? e )))          (* (: (* c1 c2)) (: e))       )
    ( (* (?  e1) (* (?c c ) (? e2)))          (* (: c ) (* (: e1) (: e2)))  )
    ( (* (* (? e1) (? e2)) (? e3))            (* (: e1) (* (: e2) (: e3)))  )
    ( (+ (?c c1) (+ (?c c2) (? e )))          (+ (: (+ c1 c2)) (: e))       )
    ( (+ (?  e1) (+ (?c c ) (? e2)))          (+ (: c ) (+ (: e1) (: e2)))  )
    ( (+ (+ (? e1) (? e2)) (? e3))            (+ (: e1) (+ (: e2) (: e3)))  )
    ( (+ (* (?c c1) (? e)) (* (?c c2) (? e))) (* (: (+ c1 c2)) (: e))       )
    ( (* (? e1) (+ (? e2) (? e3)))            (+ (* (: e1) (: e2))
                                                 (* (: e1) (: e3)))         )
    ))

(define algsimp (simplifier algebra-rules))

;; Symbolic Differentiation

(define deriv-rules
  '(
    ( (dd (?c c) (? v))              0                                 )
    ( (dd (?v v) (? v))              1                                 )
    ( (dd (?v u) (? v))              0                                 )
    ( (dd (+ (? x1) (? x2)) (? v))   (+ (dd (: x1) (: v))
                                        (dd (: x2) (: v)))             )
    ( (dd (* (? x1) (? x2)) (? v))   (+ (* (: x1) (dd (: x2) (: v)))
                                        (* (dd (: x1) (: v)) (: x2)))  )
    ( (dd (** (? x) (?c n)) (? v))   (* (* (: n) (+ (: x) (: (- n 1))))
                                        (dd (: x) (: v)))              )
    ))

(define dsimp (simplifier deriv-rules))

(define scheme-rules
  '(( (square (?c n)) (: (* n n)) )
    ( (fact 0) 1 )
    ( (fact (?c n)) (* (: n) (fact (: (- n 1)))) )
    ( (fib 0) 0 )
    ( (fib 1) 1 )
    ( (fib (?c n)) (+ (fib (: (- n 1)))
                      (fib (: (- n 2)))) )
    ( ((? op) (?c e1) (?c e2)) (: (op e1 e2)) ) ))

(define scheme-evaluator (simplifier scheme-rules))
```

I'm running it in DrRacket with the R5RS, and the first problem I ran into was that atom? was an undefined identifier.  So, I found that I could add the following:

```
    (define (atom? x) ; atom? is not in a pair or null (empty)
    (and (not (pair? x))
    (not (null? x))))
```

I then tried to figure out how to actually run this beast, so I watched the video again and saw him use the following:

```
(dsimp '(dd (+ x y) x))
```

As stated by Sussman, I should get back (+ 1 0).  Instead, using R5RS I seem to be breaking in the extend-dictionary procedure at the line:

```
((eq? (cadr v) dat) dictionary)
```

The specific error it's returning is: mcdr: expects argument of type mutable-pair; given #f

When using neil/sicp I'm breaking in the evaluate procedure  at the line:

```
(apply (eval (lookup (car form) dictionary)
                   user-initial-environment)
```

The specific error it's returning is: unbound identifier in module in: user-initial-environment

So, with all of that being said, I'd appreciate some help, or the a good nudge in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code is from 1991. Since R5RS came out in 1998, the code must be written for R4RS (or older).
One of the differences between R4RS and later Schemes is that the empty list was interpreted as false in the R4RS and as true in R5RS.

Example:

```
  (if '() 1 2)
```

gives 1 in R5RS but 2 in R4RS.

Procedures such as assq could therefore return '() instead of false.
This is why you need to change the definition of extend-directory to:

```
(define (extend-dictionary pat dat dictionary)
  (let ((vname (variable-name pat)))
    (let ((v (assq vname dictionary)))
      (cond ((not v)
             (cons (list vname dat) dictionary))
            ((eq? (cadr v) dat) dictionary)
            (else 'failed)))))
```

Also back in those days map was called mapcar. Simply replace mapcar with map.

The error you saw in DrRacket was:

```
mcdr: expects argument of type <mutable-pair>; given '()
```

This means that cdr got an empty list. Since an empty list has
no cdr this gives an error message. Now DrRacket writes mcdr
instead of cdr, but ignore that for now.

Best advice: Go through one function at a time and test it with
a few expressions in the REPL. This is easier than figuring
everything out at once.

Finally begin your program with:

```
(define user-initial-environment (scheme-report-environment 5))
```

Another change from R4RS (or MIT Scheme in 1991?).

**Addendum:**

This code http://pages.cs.brandeis.edu/~mairson/Courses/cs21b/sym-diff.scm almost runs.
Prefix it in DrRacket with:

```
#lang r5rs
(define false #f)
(define user-initial-environment (scheme-report-environment 5))
(define mapcar map)
```

And in extend-directory change the (null? v) to (not v).
That at least works for simple expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm using the neil/sicp, but felt it was beneficial to provide the different errors from both.  I made the adjustments as suggested which led me to some "false" errors which I tried changing to #f's, which led me to another mutable-paid error.  --  At the end of the day, I guess I'm just trying to learn the code, but I can't find code that works.  Do you know of any working code from this video lesson that can be found? To your advice, I definitely will continue to try going through one function at a time, but this is pretty heady code for my current lisp expertise.

Comment: I added a link to a newer version used at Brandeis.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://rajiv.sg/blog/2012/07/01/sicp-pattern-matching-and-rule-based-substitution-lecture-with-mit-scheme/) is the code that works for me with mit-scheme (Release 9.1.1).

Answer (score 2):

You also may use [this code](http://code.google.com/p/stolzen/source/browse/trunk/sicp/chapter2/4A/mattern-matching.scm). It runs on Racket.

For running "eval" without errors, the following needed to be added

```
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(apply (eval '+ ns) '(1 2 3))
```

Comment: please update the link to the code, may be gist github, tks!